# Shiny with mongolite query

Tags: r, shiny, mongolite

I would like to run a mongolite query within a reactive context in Shiny. The db connection parameters are pre-loaded and not shown below. (Note: the loadData function appears in the first block of code). The query runs just fine outside of a reactive context.

I can't seem to find a working example online with Shiny and mongolite working together. Any help would be greatly appreciated. In the simplified example below, I'm simply trying to get Shiny to return the number of rows in the query results.

Thanks

```
loadData <- function() {
  # Connect to the database
  db <- mongo(collection = collectionName,
              url = sprintf(
                "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s",
                options()$mongodb$username,
                options()$mongodb$password,
                options()$mongodb$host,
                databaseName))
  # Read all the entries
  data <- db$find(query)
  data
}


server <- function(input, output) {

   queryResults <- reactive({

    ########----------BRING IN USER QUERY PARAMETERS----------########
    var1 <- "satisfaction"
    var2 <- "performance"
    var1path <- 20072
    var2path <- 30033

    ########----------DEFINE QUERY PARAMETERS----------########
    var1 <- as.character(var1)
    var1 <- paste(var1, collapse = "|")
    var1JSON <- toJSON (var1)

    var2 <- as.character(var2)
    var2 <- paste(var2, collapse = "|")
    var2JSON <- toJSON (var2)

    #-----Creating JSONs for taxonomy codes

    var1path <- as.character(var1path)
    var1path <- paste(var1path, collapse = "|")
    var1path <- toJSON (var1path)

    var2path <- as.character(var2path)
    var2path <- paste(var2path, collapse = "|")
    var2path <- toJSON (var2path)

    ########----------QUERY STRUCTURE AND EXECUTION----------#########
    query <- c('
               {"$and":
               [
               {"$or":
               [ 
               {"Var1": { "$regex": ',var1JSON,' }},
               {"Var1Path": { "$regex": ',var1path,' }}
               ]
               },

               {"$or":
               [
               {"Var2": { "$regex": ',var2JSON,' }},
               {"Var2Path": { "$regex": ',var2path,' }}
               ]
               }
               ]
               }
               ')

    stuff <- loadData()
    stuff
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText(nrow(queryResults()))
```

Comment: I can't see what `queryResutls()` is *reacting* to - can you set one of your `vars` to be read in from a user input (e.g. `input$var1`) and see what that does?

Answer (score 4):

As I can't reproduce your code I'm setting up my own data, but hopefully this will show you a working example of `mongolite` & `shiny`.

**Data**

Input some data into mongodb

```
library(mongolite)

## create dummy data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 region = c("r1", "r1", "r2"))

> df
id region
1  1     r1
2  2     r1
3  3     r2

## insert into database
mong <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost")
mong$insert(df)
# Complete! Processed total of 3 rows.
# [1] TRUE
```

**shiny**

Here is a very basic app that responds to user input. I've tried to stay consistent with your structure

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(mongolite)

loadData <- function(qry){
  mong <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost",
                verbose = TRUE)

  df <- mong$find(qry)
  return(df)
}


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  qryResults <- reactive({

    ## This bit responds to the user selection 
    ## which makes it 'reactive'
    region <- list(region = input$si_region)

    qry <- paste0('{ "region" : "',region , '"}')
    df <- loadData(qry)
    return(df)
  })

  output$qry_results <- renderDataTable({
    qryResults()
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText(nrow(qryResults()))

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(navbarPage("mongo query",
                   sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                       selectInput(inputId = "si_region", label = "Select region", choices = c("r1", "r2"))
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                       verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text1"),
                       dataTableOutput(outputId = "qry_results")
                     )
                   )))
```